# Can you do a "stream.get" from Facebook Javascript SDK?

Tags: facebook, api, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to build [a cross browser extension with Crossrider](http://crossrider.com) which fetches the Facebook Stream and shows it on Google+.

Everything is set, the Facebook App, the connect itself, but the only missing piece in the puzzle is "stream.get" which I can't find how to call this API method with the JS SDK.

Is this possible at all ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed with an access token with the javascript api which is the graph replacement for stream.get.  You could also run a FQL query against the stream table.  Both I believe would need "read_stream" extended permission.